# Dynamically Use Spring Annotations for Redis and Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Consider the following class

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;


@Document(indexName = "index_name")
@RedisHash("filter_name")

class Index {

}
```

I have a usecase where in usage of elasticsearch or redis would be by the user's choice, one way of implementation is having separate class for each, which works, but isn't elegent.
Is it possible to disable a specific annotation in runtime.

Comment: Annotations are just metadata. If there is no elasticsearch on the classpath/active the annotations don't do anything, the same for Redis.

Comment: I have both in classpath, have tried ConditionalOnProperty for repository and configuration beans, but still they connect to the redis or elastic based on document or redishash annotation

Comment: You will ofcourse need to disable on or the other (you can exclude the auto configuration for that).

Comment: Thanks, excluding autoconfig and using manual configuration helps, now i am able to do the same